# RTK Query: Use result of two endpoint in one component

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

[Main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrtiH.jpg)

I have cardList component, who get list of movies from first request and display it. That's work fine.

```
export const movieApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "movieApi",
  tagTypes: ["Movies"],
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/" }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getMovies: builder.query<MoviesArray, number | void>({
      query: (page = 1) => ({
        url: "movie/top_rated?api_key=3046e4e04c3ba6250edd1d3c6eb2d4ad&language=en-US&page=" + page,
        method: "GET",
      })
    }),


    searchMovies: builder.mutation<MoviesArray, string | void>({
      query: (searchValue) => ({
        url: `search/movie?api_key=3046e4e04c3ba6250edd1d3c6eb2d4ad&language=en-US&query=${searchValue}&page=1&include_adult=true`,
        method: "GET",
      }),
    }),
  })
});

export const { useGetMoviesQuery, useSearchMoviesMutation } = movieApi;
```

The problem is that i can't display in the same component result from search input. I get the new found array but i don't know how to replace old result to new result.

Yea, i can make new route with new "SearcMovie" component and put there search endpoint. But i want to more clear solution if it exist.

[RTKQ state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLwbV.png)

I tried providesTags witch invalidatesTags. But i think i'm lost. It's was more easy to do the same job in Redux/Saga or simple RTK when you have actions and state.

[VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJAZC.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had to read this multiple times before I understood your question, but I think I get it now:

You have a grid component which displays a particular page of search results.  If the user has entered a search term then these results come from the `search/movie` API URL (your `searchMovies` endpoint).  But if there is no search term then the results come from the `movie/top_rated` API URL (your `getMovies` endpoint).  You aren't sure how to switch back and forth between these two endpoints.

#### Okay Solution: Two Endpoints

What you are suggesting is that you use both endpoints in the same component.  Yes, you can do that.

You have to be careful that you do not break the rules of hooks by calling  a `useQuery` hook conditionally.  Instead, you can use the RTK [`skip`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/conditional-fetching) option or [`skipToken`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#skiptoken) to avoid unnecessarily calling one endpoint when the other is needed.

You can assign the result object that want to an intermediate variable before destructuring, that was you only have one `isFetching` variable.

```
const MyComponent = ({ page = 1, searchTerm = '' }: { page?: number; searchTerm?: string }) => {
  
  // Check if the searchTerm is empty.
  const hasSearchTerm = !!searchTerm;

  // Call both hooks, but skip one.
  const topResult = useGetMoviesQuery(page, { skip: hasSearchTerm });
  const searchResult = useSearchMoviesQuery({ page, searchTerm }, { skip: !hasSearchTerm });

  // Choose the applicable result and destructure.
  const currentResult = hasSearchTerm ? searchResult : topResult;
  const { data, isError, isFetching } = currentResult; 

  // Render the movies.
  return (
    /* ... */
  )
}
```

You need to make 2 changes to your `searchMovies` endpoint:

1. It is a `query`, not a `mutation`.
2. It should accept the `page` in the arguments.

```
searchMovies: builder.query<MoviesArray, { searchTerm: string; page?: number }>({
  query: ({ searchTerm, page = 1 }) => ({
    url: `search/movie?api_key=3046e4e04c3ba6250edd1d3c6eb2d4ad&language=en-US&query=${searchTerm}&page=${page}&include_adult=true`,
    method: "GET",
  }),
}),
```

#### Better Solution: One Endpoint

You can keep the component code a lot cleaner if you handle the URL switching in the RTK endpoints.  I personally prefer this approach.

We define a single endpoint that takes the `page` and the `searchValue`, which are both optional.  The `url` changes depending on whether or not there is a `searchValue`.

```
const MyComponent = ({ page, searchTerm }: { page?: number; searchTerm?: string }) => {

  // No complex logic here!
  const { data, isError, isFetching } = useGetMoviePageQuery({ page, searchTerm }); 

  // Render the movies.
  return (
    /* ... */
  )
}
```

```
export const movieApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "movieApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/" }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getMoviePage: builder.query<MoviesArray, { page?: number; searchTerm?: string }>({
      query: ({ page = 1, searchTerm = '' }) => ({
        // Use a ternary to switch between the two URLs.
        url: searchTerm
          ? `search/movie?api_key=API_KEY&language=en-US&query=${searchValue}&page=${page}&include_adult=true`
          : `movie/top_rated?api_key=API_KEY&language=en-US&page=${page}`,
        method: "GET",
      })
    })
  })
});

export const { useGetMoviePageQuery } = movieApi;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Linda for your response. Your solution is clear and effective. I will try this. For now i'm done with separation a independent components and each has their own query.

Now after one week of study RTKQ it little bit clearly how to do. I am very appreciative you for help.